# WPF / Silverlight - Mapping API

Tags: wpf, api, maps

I am about to start on a project where I need to display maps with cross streets and possibly directions.  I know there are a lot of API for the web, but I was wondering what the best solution is for a desktop application.

I know of Bing Maps and I believe there are some Google Maps solutions out there as well.  Any help or information on good mapping API's would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look at using the [ESRI mapping controls](http://resources.esri.com/arcgisserver/apis/silverlight/). It's nice, relatively easy to use, lots of samples (mostly in silverlight, but thats easy to convert), and has the power of ESRI. What could be better?

if you have a bing maps developer key, you can even use the bing tiles.

Comment: This looks very promising, and simple to understand and implement.  Thanks for the great pointer.

Comment: glad to help.  We are partners with ESRI and are using this in a commercial product :-)